# Thumbnail with an Array adapter in a list view

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Is it possible to show a thumbnail with a  Array adapter in a list? The thumbnail is always the same.

```
final ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 );
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

I populate my list with volley.

Comment: Not sure with ArrayAdapter, but you can achieve this by subclassing ArrayAdapter and getView method or creating your own Adapter

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter is usually used for populating a ListView widget from array or list of primitive values like String. When you are creating an ArrayAdapter with `ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 );` as the second parameter you have R.layout.simple_list_item_1 which is a layout with only one TextView, so if you need a ImageView alongside a TextView, you will need to create new view that will contain TextView and ImageView widgets and create custom class that will extend Adapter where you will use the newly created view and populate it's views with your content.